# Azure Storage table movement with data from environment to environment

Tags: azure, storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account

I have one Azure storage table in DEV environment with 100 rows (example). I would like to move the data and table as it is from DEV to SIT then UAT goes like to PROD.
so basically its like lift and shift of the table with data.

Is there any solution available in Azure portal or commands etc?

I heard with Azure Copy we can achieve this but not sure with respect to tables

Example let's say we have Employee table  with columns as emp id, name, address, contact,email etc in my DEV environment and this table being used as Read purpose in the code
when my code move to SIT and UAT similarly I should move this dependency data to SIT and UAT
so here i need to move Employee table with all records and structure from one environment to another

Comment: You could do this using ADF (Azure Data Factory) : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/copying-azure-table-storage-using-azure-data-factory-adf/ba-p/3062401

Comment: It would be great if you provide more details like your table structure and what you tried. Then only community members can help you.

Comment: vijaya - Example let's say we have Employee table  with columns as emp id, name,address, contact,email etc in my DEV environment and this table being used as Read purpose in the code 
when my code move to SIT and UAT similarly I should move this dependency data to SIT and UAT 
so here i need to move Employee table with all records and structure from one environment to another

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Quentin Geff , **you can use Azure data factory** to move data from one table another table. For sample purpose i have taken 3 rows in your case you can use 100 rows also.

- Created two table storages as source and destination.
- Created 2 linked services in adf monitor tool for source and destination tables as shown in below image.
  [image]
- **To create linked service**, Go to azure monitor tool>Linked services>> + New>>Azure table storage>> fill the required details like linked service name,subscription and storage account name and select Create.
- **In your case source will be the DEV environment and destination will be uat or sit environment**.
- Then you need to create 2 data sets for these 2 linked services.
- **To create Data Sets** Got to Author tool>>Data sets >> New dataset>>select Azure table storage>>Select the created LS

[image]

- Then in pipeline take copy activity. Select dev environment data set as source and uat or sit environment as Sink.
  [image]

Configure sink as shown below, to copy partition key same as source table.
[image]

- Run pipeline and data will be copied to uat or sit environment.
  [image]
  [image]
- You can use another copy activity in same pipeline and configure source as uat/sit table and sink as prod environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the data migration yourself in code you could export all data to CSV (BLOB Storage or local file storage) and then import it to the target table either by code or Azure Storage Explorer.

I wrote a little library to make the CSV export easier:

```cs
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.CSV;

TableServiceClient tableServiceClient = new(connectionString);
TableClient tableClient = tableServiceClient.GetTableClient("tablename");

// Export all rows from the table to a CSV file
using StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("test.csv");
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);

// Export all rows as CSV to Azure BLob Storage
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new(BlobConnectionString, "testcontainer");
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("test.csv");
var stream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true, new BlobOpenWriteOptions() { HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/csv" } });
using StreamWriter writer = new(stream);
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);

// Import all rows from a CSV file to the table
using StreamReader reader = new("test.csv");
await _tableClient.ImportCSVAsync(reader);
```

[Source](https://github.com/ThomasPe/Azure.Data.Tables-Extensions#csv-export--import)